# Plotly - add_hline from specified candle

Tags: pandas, plotly

I'm trying to add horizontal lines starting at `candleOfInterest` ('2020-03-21').

I can add using `fig.add_hline(y=orh)` but how do I set the x value to start at `candleOfInterest` and ending at '2020-03-31'?

[image]

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
   
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF


df = genMockDataFrame(15,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=157)


candleOfInterest = '2020-03-21'

#open range high and low
orh = df.loc[candleOfInterest]["High"]
orl = df.loc[candleOfInterest]["Low"]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,

                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])

fig.add_hline(y=orh)
fig.add_hline(y=orl)


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `go.Scatter` between the starting and ending point of each horizontal line segment, with the arguments `mode='lines'` and `showlegend=False` depending on whether you want these annotations to display in the legend or not.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[candleOfInterest, '2020-03-31'], y=[orh]*2, mode='lines', line=dict(color='black'), showlegend=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[candleOfInterest, '2020-03-31'], y=[orl]*2, mode='lines', line=dict(color='black'), showlegend=False))
```

Output:
[image]